# Combine rows into one cell

Tags: excel

I am wondering if there is an easy way to combine all the rows for each Hl7 message into one cell, I have a huge list of HL7 messages and each message ends with angle bracket ">". Can this be done using a formula or a VBA code?

Here is what I am trying to achieve

[image: Original]

[image: Transformed]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an alternate solution. It's not elegant but formats exactly as you've shown in the above images, with a carriage return at the end of each line, the ">" removed, and an empty cell in between messages. I put the result in column B so I could see if it was working properly. You could of course tailor it to your needs.

```
Sub DoMessages()

    Dim HL7Message As String
    Dim newHL7Message As String
    Dim i As Integer: i = 2
    Dim j As Integer: j = 1
    Dim lastRow As Integer

    lastRow = Sheets(1).Cells(1000, "A").End(xlUp).Row 'I used "1000" for the sake of this test code. Change as required.

    HL7Message = Cells(1, 1).Value

    For i = 1 To lastRow
        newHL7Message = Cells(i, 1).Value
        If Not newHL7Message = ">" Then
            If HL7Message = "" Then 'This 'If-Then-Else' keeps from there being an extra CR at the beginning of each cell
                HL7Message = newHL7Message
            Else
                HL7Message = HL7Message & vbCrLf & newHL7Message
            End If
        Else
            Sheets(1).Cells(j, 2) = HL7Message
            HL7Message = ""
            j = j + 2
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:
I think I originally misunderstood the goal. Please try the below and report back.

```
Sub Join()
Dim X as Variant
Dim C as range
Dim I as Integer
Dim str as string
For Each C in Workbooks("TEST").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("a1").currentregion
   str = str & C 'Changed to make sure they are written in the correct order
Next C
X = Split(str, ">")
For I = 0 to ubound(x)
Workbooks("TEST").Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(I+1,2) = x(I) & ">"
Next I
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you give me more details? Which column are the messages are in? Where would you like the output? Is the number of message fixed or variable? What is the workbook name? What is the sheet name? This code is adaptable to make work, but I cannot do so without more information.

Comment: all the messages are in column A. the out put can be in the same sheet. the number of segments in the message is variable. Workbook Name = TEST. sheet Name = Sheet1

Comment: See my edit. I believe I originally misunderstood the goal. The above will put each separate HL7 code in it's own cell, not all the codes together in one cell.

Comment: thanks for your help, it is still combining all HL7 segments into one line backwards  see example below >ORC|RE||D347|||||||||^||||^|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||PV1||IP|MI^MI17^^||||^|^||||||||||IP||||||||||||||||||||||||||201502240000|PID||5407^^^CORPORATE|103|00760164|TEST^PATIENT^^^||19000101|M|^^|||||||||454|||||||||||||||||||||||||||MSH|^~\&|HL7|1|APP||20150225000114||ORU|201502250000310783|T|2.3|201502250000310783|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||>OBX|1|CE|%ABI^ANTIBODY IDENT^LAB||transfusion reaction.|||||||||201502250000|SB^Test Performed

Comment: Edited for the order. They should now be in the correct order and each HL7 code should be in it's own cell.

Comment: I can use this code for something else. I really appreciate your time and help. Porcupine911 provided a VBA code that works exactly the way I want it

Comment: there is no error, it compiles all the lines into one single line

Answer (score 0):

IF you want output as highlighted from the (over?) simplified input data example on the left, then the two formulae as shown would achieve this, prior to selecting all, Copy, Paste Special, Values and filtering on ColumnC to select and delete rows showing `FALSE`:

[image: SO28772576 example]